# (Discord.js) How do i get all the members connected to the voice channels of a category?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commando

So, i'm making a command called "movedebat" to move all the members connected to the voice channels of a channel category to a channel dedicated to debates.

To achieve my goal, I am trying to get the list of all the connected members, to then use a for(member in members) loop and move each one of the members.

```
    let debate_channel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.id === '497910775512563742');
    let group_of_channels = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.id === '497908108803440653');
    let connected_members = message.guild.channels.filter((c => parentID === group_of_channels.id)&&(c => c.type == 2)).members;
    if(message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')){
        for(connected_member in connected_members){
            console.log(connected_member.id); 
            connected_member.setVoiceChannel(debate_channel)
                .then(() => console.log(`Moved ${connected_member.displayName}`))
                .catch(console.error);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't work at all. I do not get any error, neither by the bot itself in discord or in the console.
The only thing I get is a warning `DeprecationWarning: Collection#filterArray: use Collection#filter instead`, but I Googled it and people seemed to say it was not important.
i think that the problematic line is the 'let connected_members(...)members;' one.
I should mention that i expect to see at least 1 member id in my console, but i don't get any, that means that the for loop is not 'executed'.

Thank you for reading me, I hope someone can help ! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you declare `connected_members`, you should use a *single* function in [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter).
- `Collection.filter()` returns another Collection, of which `members` is not a property. You'll have to iterate through *each channel* to get its members.
- [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) "iterates over all non-Symbol, enumerable *properties of an object*" (MDN). In a Collection ([Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)), the elements aren't properties, but key-value pairs. You can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead in this context.

```js
if (message.member.permissions.missing('ADMINISTRATOR')) return;

const channels = message.guild.channels.filter(c => c.parentID === '497908108803440653' && c.type === 'voice');

for (const [channelID, channel] of channels) {
  for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
    member.setVoiceChannel('497910775512563742')
      .then(() => console.log(`Moved ${member.user.tag}.`))
      .catch(console.error);
  }
}
```

*Side note: Use `Map.get()` for finding a value from a Collection by its ID.*

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much ! I'm new to the javascript environment, i didn't know that the for(..of..) existed. Thank you !!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to accept this answer with the checkmark on the left if it solves your problem.