# User connected to voice channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to know is it possible to know if any member is connected to a specific voice channel in discord.js v12.2.0. I've been sticking in this question in recent days. Please tell me if you have any clues on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570791/discord-js-how-do-i-get-all-the-members-connected-to-the-voice-channels-of-a-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to know if the member **is** connected to a VoiceChannel or listen to the [voiceStateUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event so I'll cover both cases.

## Checking if the member is connected to a VoiceChannel

```js
const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GuildID"); // Getting the guild.
const Member = Guild.members.cache.get("UserID"); // Getting the member.

if (Member.voice.channel) { // Checking if the member is connected to a VoiceChannel.
    // The member is connected to a voice channel.
    // https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState
    console.log(`${Member.user.tag} is connected to ${Member.voice.channel.name}!`);
} else {
    // The member is not connected to a voice channel.
    console.log(`${Member.user.tag} is not connected.`);
};
```

## Listening to the voiceStateUpdate event

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => { // Listeing to the voiceStateUpdate event
    if (newVoiceState.channel) { // The member connected to a channel.
        console.log(`${newVoiceState.member.user.tag} connected to ${newVoiceState.channel.name}.`);
    } else if (oldVoiceState.channel) { // The member disconnected from a channel.
        console.log(`${oldVoiceState.member.user.tag} disconnected from ${oldVoiceState.channel.name}.`)
    };
});
```

Comment: I know about this, the thing that I am asking for is I don't know how the bot keeps tracking if the specific channel has any member connected or not. I want to make a thing like when someone connected to voice channel 1, the bot shows the voice channel 2. And if the member from voice channel disconnect, then hide channel 2. if there are member connected channel 1 or 2, then show channel 3

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you're asking if you can check if there are any users connected to a certain channel? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want the bot to keep checking if a certain channel has any member connected or not.

Comment: You can use [VoiceChannel.members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) (Collection) to check if there are any members connected to the channel.